# Query to put two rows together on Google Big Query?

Tags: sql, database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, etl

I have two tables with similar structures on Google Big Query:

**TABLE 1**

| dt_sell | cod_material | cod_channel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 12 | vd |
| 2022-01-02 | 14 | vd |

**TABLE 1**

| dt_sell | cod_material | cod_channel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 12 | ecm |
| 2022-01-01 | 13 | ecm |

I need to put the rows of one table under the other one, like this:

| dt_sell | cod_material | cod_channel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 12 | vd |
| 2022-01-02 | 14 | vd |
| 2022-01-01 | 12 | ecm |
| 2022-01-01 | 13 | ecm |

How could I do this by running a query on Big Query? I can't create a new table for it, it needs to be on a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [UNION](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#union)

```sql
SELECT dt_sell, cod_material, cod_channel FROM table_one
UNION 
SELECT dt_sell, cod_material, cod_channel FROM table_two
```